# prototype PeriodicalExecuter move div effect

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs, scriptaculous

Trying to move a div down while the request is being made then move the div back up in it's original position on complete. But its only getting up with each request. Here is the code

```
new PeriodicalExecuter(function() {
    new Effect.Move('content', {
        x:0,
        y:15,
        duration:1
    });;
    new Ajax.Updater('content','/getcontent', {
        asynchronous:true,
        evalScripts:true,
        onComplete:function(request, json) {
            new Effect.Move('content', {x:0,y:-15,duration:1});
        },
        insertion:Insertion.Top,
        requestHeaders:['X-Update', 'content']
    })
}, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're expecting the onComplete Move to execute after the first Move has completed. This is unlikely to happen because both Move and Ajax.Updater are asynchronous. The solution is to switch to absolute Moves and to cancel the original Move before the second one conflicts with it.

```
$('content').store('originalOffset', $('content').cumulativeOffset());

new PeriodicalExecuter(function() {
    $('content').store(
     'move', 
      new Effect.Move('content', {
        x:$('content').retrieve('originalOffset').left,
        y:$('content').retrieve('originalOffset').top + 15,
        duration:1,
        mode: 'absolute'
      })
    );
    new Ajax.Updater('content','/getcontent', {
        asynchronous:true,
        evalScripts:true,
        onCreate: function() {
         $('content').retrieve('move').cancel();
        },
        onComplete:function(request, json) {
            new Effect.Move(
             'content', {
              x:$('content').retrieve('originalOffset').left,
              y:$('content').retrieve('originalOffset').top,
              duration:1,
              mode: 'absolute'
             }
            );
        },
        insertion:Insertion.Top,
        requestHeaders:['X-Update', 'content']
    })
}, 5);
```